# gradle application does not recognise import in intellij

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle, spring-boot

I have imported a gradle project (spring application) in intellij and intellij does not recognised the import(example) :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import
```

but in command line it is building successfully with(./gradlew clean build) but I would like to be able to work in intellij

Any idea, I do not master gradle, there is way to do clean

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details. Which version of IntelliJ? How did you import the project?

Comment: You should try to update your dependencies in Intellij Idea. To do it, click the refresh button in the Gradle tool window

Comment: when I do a fresh, even java package is not recognized as a source root or resources is not recognised as resource root. I am using intelliJ 14 . When Importing I have chosen : use default gradle wrapper